# Server cannot serve static files

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, hosting, plesk, ionos

I'm using IONOS linux vps with Plesk Obsidian to host my projects.
I used .NetCore to create the backend api
and React as the front end.

Backend deployment works perfectly, I'm using apache2 to serve the backend. and I am able to call my api at `https://www.mywebsite.com/api/controller`
but I'm struggling with the react deployment. (event though it should be easier)

**What I tried :**

- The simplest approach which some tutorials recommended, copied the `build` folder contents to `httpdocs` folder (which is set as the document root by default in Plesk)
- I also tried putting the build files in `/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs` (which worked before using https) and included the configuration in `apache2.conf` file :

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/
   # Relax Apache security settings
   <Directory /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs>
     Allow from all
     Options -MultiViews
      Require all granted
   </Directory>
  ```
- I also tried specifying the configs in a separate file in `sites-enabled` folder.

And all of the above yield the same result : when I call `https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html` or a static file that exists in the same folder `https://www.mywebsite.com/pic.png` I always get `404` and the request fails.

what is strange is that it was working fine before I changed from `http` to `https`.

The configs for .netcore :
**http :**

```
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}

ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}access.log common
```

**https :**

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:5001/
ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAlias *.mywebsite.com
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}access.log common
```

and the service file :

```
[Unit]
Description=Example .NET Web API App running on UBUNTU

[Service]
WorkingDirectory= /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/publish
ExecStart=dotnet /var/www/vhosts/mywebsite.com/publish/API.dll
Restart=always
# Restart service after 10 seconds if the dotnet service crashes:
RestartSec=10
KillSignal=SIGINT
SyslogIdentifier=my-web
User=root
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I also tried moving the frontend files to the publish folder, but nothing seems to work.

anyone has an idea on what I should try to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

1. you need add `app.UseStaticFiles();`into `Startup.cs ---> Configure`method

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // other code...
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    //other code...
}
```

2. create dir `wwwwroot` in your api project

```
.
├── Controllers
└── wwwroot
```

3. add your file to `wwwroot` dir(like 1.jpeg)

```
.
├── Controllers
└── wwwroot
    └── 1.jpeg
```

4. wget `localhost:5000/1.jpeg`

NOTE:

- do not conflict with routing in wwwroot subdirectories
- build file (1.jpeg) into bin

you can see 1.jpeg in current folder

#### update:

If you want to deploy separately, for example, react app and webapi are not on the same server, then you need to use a proxy like nginx,This is a relatively recommended practice

If you don’t want to deploy separately, then netcore supports spa

NOTE:

> I am using Angular, I am not sure if it is suitable for React
>
> - the following code is based on netcore 2.1
> - the react app directory must be `ClientApp` (Changeable, but must ensure that the code is consistent with the path)
> - React compilation output folder must be `dist` (Changeable, but must ensure that the code is consistent with the path)

- ### create dir `ClientApp` in your api project
- ### move all files of  react app into `ClientApp`
- ### build react app
- ### add code into `Startup` of `ConfigureServices`

  ```cs
  services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
  {
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";//dist is the react compilation output directory
  });
  ```
- ### add code into `Startup` of `Configure`

  ```cs
  app.UseSpa(cfg =>
  {
      cfg.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
      cfg.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:4200");
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
          //cfg.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");// use angular cli
      }
  });
  ```
- ### build webapi

Now you can run Webapi directly and access React through `localhost:4200`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! but in this case where should I put the `.htaccess` file?
and where can I enable it from? because all the tutorials are assuming that the static files are put in `/var/www/vhosts/html`. and I cant seem to enable it in my case.

Comment: I don’t know what's `.htaccess` file, but if you just get this file, you can put it in `wwwroot`,and I updated the answer, you can try it